# Solving inequality leaves CRootOf in answer

Tags: octave, sympy

when I try to solve this inequality x^3 + 3*x > 3 I get this output:

```matlab
    octave:5> eqn = x^3 + 3*x > 3
    eqn = (sym)

     3
    x  + 3⋅x > 3

    octave:6> solve(eqn, x)
    ans = (sym)

                   ⎛ 3             ⎞
    x < ∞ ∧ CRootOf⎝x  + 3⋅x - 3, 0⎠ < x
```

But when I try to solve simpler inequality everything works fine:

```matlab
    eqn = abs(x^2-3)>3
    eqn = (sym)

    │ 2    │
    │x  - 3│ > 3

    octave:4> solve(eqn, x)
    ans = (sym) (-∞ < x ∧ x < -√6) ∨ (√6 < x ∧ x < ∞)
```

What can I do with this **CRoot**?

Comment: This isn't valid MATLAB syntax so I've removed the MATLAB tag

Comment: Are you really using `scipy`, a python package?  This looks more like you are using the `Octave` port of `sympy`.  Get the context right, in code, subject line, and tags.

Comment: I don't use octave but in sympy you can use evalf to calculate an approximation for the rootof.